# Conversion between C string and std::string lead to garbled text in platform specific way

Tags: c++, windows, string, type-conversion

I was dealing with a platform specific bug today in which on a Windows machine a certain string would be quite garbled, but not on a Mac.  The bug had to do with several lines that did both explicit and implicit conversions between `std::string` and `const char *`.  Basically, I had a function with the signature

```
void foo(const std::string &id);
```

where foo at some point prints the string.  On Windows, if called like below it would print the id string with various levels of corruption (garbling the first few characters or as much as the whole string)

```
std::string mystring = bar();
const char *id = mystring.c_str();
foo(id); // pass the C style string in because I thought that's what it took
```

I corrected the error by calling `foo` correctly:

```
std::string mystring = bar();
foo(mystring);
```

I can't figure out a few things though, like

- What was the source of the bug?
- Why was it platform specific?
- Is implicit conversion between `const char *` and `std::string` ever safe?

Comment: The third point's answer is not when it's a null string or not pointing to a valid string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess and say that the code in your question isn't representative of your real code. The symptom sounds like memory being reused, which means the string isn't valid anymore at the time of the `foo` call. You could get that by using `c_str` on a temporary, for example `const char *id = bar().c_str();`.

Comment: Totally right.  In writing the question I changed the code removing `bar().c_str()` because I didn't think through the fact that the return from `bar` would be temporary.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

There are two likely possibilities, and from just what you've said, we can't tell which:

1. `foo` mishandles the case where it gets a reference to a temporary. For example, perhaps it stashes a pointer to its parameter somewhere and other code uses it after `foo` returns.
2. The data in `mystring` contains embedded zero bytes and the length is lost when you call `c_str`.

Comment: Hadn't thought of #2.

Comment: Embedded zero bytes would cause truncation, not garbling.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Truncation can cause garbling. For example, consider if the last byte in the string indicates its encoding format. Truncation would mean the last byte would be changed, causing the encoding format to be misunderstood, causing garbling. Or consider if multibyte is the default unless the string is an odd number of characters ... again, truncation would cause garbling.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is going on, but is there any reason not to copy the result of c_str() into a buffer you own, call foo() on it, and destroy the buffer you created? If that doesn't fix it, it is a problem with foo() only rather than the implementation or some conflict between the implementation and foo().